# Radial gradient equation

Tags: graphics, modeling

Given:

A point P, circle 1 and circle 2's positions and radii

What is:

The equation for T, the 'mix level' between color 1 and 2 (a value between 0 to 1)

Many radial gradient equations only apply to concentric circles or circles that share a position.  I'm looking for something that matches the image below, created using Quartz (Core Graphics).  I am writing a GLSL shader, but I need to understand the math first.

[image]

Comment: How do you know that P is on the shape?  It seems to me that if you have an equation for the shape itself, the gradient should fall out easily.

Comment: What are we looking at here? Is this drawn in 2D or 3D? You say you're using Quartz, but writing a GLSL shader. Since Quartz doesn't directly support GLSL shaders, what are you applying the shader to?

Comment: Quartz is CPU-bound (slow), so I'm looking to write a GLSL fragment shader to replace Quartz for this purpose, but it has to behave the same.  It is drawn in 2D.

Comment: It will probably be implemented as a GPUImage filter once I get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in 2D, then you can write the parameters of the circle that your point lies on as:

```
x3=T*x1+(1-T)*x2
y3=T*y1+(1-T)*y2
r3=T*r1+(1-T)*r2
```

EDIT: Of course, that circle can be represented as:

```
(x3-xP)^2+(y3-yP)^2=r3^2
```

You can substitute the first 3 equations into the last (and remember that (xP, yP) is your point) to get 1 equation with only T as a variable that is quadratic in T, so it is easy to solve for T.  Doing so gives us:

```
T=(-r2*(r1-r2)+(x1-x2)*(x2-xP)+(y1-y2)(y2-yP)
    {+-}sqrt(r2^2*((x1-xP)^2+(y1-yP)^2)-2*r1*r2*((x1-xP)*(x2-xP)
               +(y1-yP)*(y2-yP))+r1^2*((x2-xP)^2+(y2-yP)^2)
               -(x2*y1-xP*y1-x1*y2+xP*y2+x1*yP-x2*yP)^2))
 /((r1-r2)^2-(x1-x2)^2-(y1-y2)^2)
```

I know that that is a bit hard to read, but it is not actually that bad mathematically.  It is just addition, multiplication, and squaring (which is really just multiplication).

Comment: Attempted to use this formula here: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#5553.1 without success.  I ran the content of the sqrt through alpha to produce a simplified version: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r1%5E2+*+x3%5E2+-+2+*+r1+*+r2+*+x3%5E2+%2B+r2%5E2+*+x3%5E2+%2B+r1%5E2+*+y3%5E2-2+*+r1+*+r2+*+y3%5E2+%2B+r2%5E2+*+y3%5E2

Comment: You forgot the parentheses around the entire numerator (starting at the very beginning and ending after the square root.

Comment: Ah, sure enough.  http://glsl.heroku.com/e#5553.2
A gradient appears! I think the circle positions got lost in the equation, though (the hard part)

Comment: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#5553.5
This is amazing! The +/- seems to affect what appears as the 'draw order' of the circles.  I think this is the key piece and the rest will follow (masking etc)

Comment: Yes; because it is a quadratic, there are two possible solutions to the equation at most points.  These correspond to the two different circles that the point can be in.

Comment: For masking, you can just make sure that T is in [0,1].

Comment: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#5553.7 It's done.  I'll be using this in my GPUImage fork @ http://github.com/jacobjennings